# PPTP refusing to connect when client is windows

Tags: networking, vpn, pptp, tcpdump

I have a PPTP server running and I can connect to it from linux. When I try from windows 7 (2 instances tested) it fails. Here's the syslog for such a conn:

```
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Client 109.xxx.158.201 control connection started
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
pppd[541]: Plugin radius.so loaded.
pppd[541]: RADIUS plugin initialized.
pppd[541]: Plugin radattr.so loaded.
pppd[541]: RADATTR plugin initialized.
pppd[541]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
pppd[541]: Using interface ppp0
pppd[541]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
pptpd[540]: GRE: Bad checksum from pppd.
pppd[541]: LCP: timeout sending Config-Requests
pppd[541]: Connection terminated.
pppd[541]: Modem hangup
pppd[541]: Exit.
pptpd[540]: GRE: read(fd=6,buffer=6075a0,len=8196) from PTY failed: status = -1 error = Input/output error, usually caused by unexpected termination of pppd, check option syntax and pppd logs
pptpd[540]: CTRL: PTY read or GRE write failed (pty,gre)=(6,7)
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[541]
pptpd[540]: CTRL: Client 109.xxx.158.201 control connection finished
```

I played with the mtu and ranged it from 900 to 1500 with no success. **My pptp options**:

```
name pptpd
refuse-pap
refuse-chap
refuse-mschap
require-mschap-v2
require-mppe-128
proxyarp
nodefaultroute
lock
nobsdcomp
ms-dns 10.10.0.1
noipx
mtu 1404
mru 1404
```

Remember! Linux client connects so ports and protocols should be enabled.

`tcpdump -i eth0 port 1723 or proto 47` shows the following gist:
https://gist.github.com/ciokan/5595640
where `109.xxx.158.201` is me, the client.

No firewalls on client. Everything disabled. Im not a network admin and I can't understand jack from that tcpdump. HALP :)

Comment: Can you check if those Win7 desktops internal firewall rules prevent inbound ip 47 access for GRE? try again please to see if client fw are off, as it seems like very problem.

Comment: Firewall off. not working ty

Comment: Can you try to add "mppe-stateful" into your pptp options?

Comment: Yes ty, same story unfortunately: `GRE: read(fd=7,buffer=60f600,len=8260) from network failed: status = -1 error = Protocol not available`

Comment: Well different error.

Comment: It looks like GRE NAT issue, you'll need to find out where the GRE is being blocked/lost.

Comment: I was probably playing with the mtu earlier but on the client side I always get: `Remote Access error 619 - A connection to the remote computer could not be established, so the port used for this connection was closed.` maybe it helps further

Comment: Ok how does client reaches vpn server, can you try to initiate another connection from another network to that server?

Comment: Network is the same as the linux desktop which connects. The connection on windows is done calling a pbk file via rasdial: `rasdial connection_name username password /phonebook:C:/path/to/file.pbk`. I had it working for a few days then it just stopped.

Comment: pbk file contents: https://gist.github.com/ciokan/5596371

Comment: your type of vpn property on Security tab is PPTP? on the client.